# Extract value of column from a line (variable)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

Okay, so I have a variable ($line) that is defined in the bash/shell script as

```
$line = "abc:123:def:345"
```

need to get this column2 = "123"

How do I extract the value of the 2nd column i.e. "123" and name it as a different variable which can be summed later on? I know you have to separate it based on the delimiter ':' but I don't know how to transfer to different variable whilst taking input from $line variable. I only ask this because for some weird reason **my code reads the first line of text file BUT doesn't perform the awk on just the first line only** so hence the sum is wrong.

```
FILE=$1
while read line
do
 awk -F: '{summation += $3;}END{print summation;}'
done < $FILE
```

-code via shell script

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think your question is complete - I can't see the second column you mention

Comment: please, small set of sample data covering the case you want to solve and 1 for a case that should not change (2 lines of data, eh?), + expected output, + your attempt to solve  your problem, + exact text of any error msgs. Use the `{}` format tool at the top of the edit box to format your code and data so it is not autowrapped by the S.O. system. Good luck.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `awk` to get second field:

```
line="abc:123:def:345"
```

```
awk -F: '{print $2}' <<< "$line"
123
```

Answer (score 3):

To assign a variable in the shell, no `$` on the left-hand side, no spaces around the `=`, and `<` and `>` are not valid quote characters

```
line="abc:123:def:345"
```

In bash, you would do this:

```
IFS=: read -ra fields <<< "$line"
```

- temporarily set `IFS` to a colon
- use the `$line` variable as input to the `read` command (a [here-string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings))
- and read the values into the `fields` array.

Bash arrays are indexed starting from zero, so to extract the 2nd field:

```
echo "${fields[1]}"   # => 123
```

Answer (score 0):

way in bash using expr

```
Line2=$(expr $line : "[^:]*:\([^:]*\)")
```

or if the fields are always 3 characters

```
Line2=${line:4:3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using plain POSIX features:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

line='abc:123:def:345'

IFS=:
# Split line on IFS into arguments
set -- $line

printf %s\\n "$2"
```

Alternate method:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

line='abc:123:def:345'

# Strip out first column
a="${line#*:}"

# Strip out remaining columns except 1st
b="${a%%:*}"

printf %s\\n "$b"
```